# RoboGuice: Using full reflection. Try using RoboGuice annotation processor for better performance

Tags: java, android, roboguice

When I start my RoboGuice android app, the following message appears in logs:

> roboguice.RoboGuice﹕ Using full reflection. Try using RoboGuice annotation processor for better performance.

What does it means?

All my activities (including my MainActivity) extend from classes of RoboGuice. Maybe I'm missing something and there's a way to improve RoboGuice performance that I'm not currently doing.

**Note: I'm using RoboBlender**

Comment: Are you using [RoboBlender?](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/RoboBlender-wiki)

Comment: Yes, @tibo, I'm using Roboblender

Comment: Based on the [code](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/bf9043c5af085408a5d26ea8e5f857e8d0a9bdab/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/RoboGuice.java#L253), it can't find your annotation database.

Comment: I had to use this `RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases(false);` on my MainActivity because RoboGuice was crashing without this.

Comment: Then that's the problem... You can change your question's title and post the crash log instead.

Comment: Thank you, @tibo! I'll do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoboGuice is based on Google [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) library, which is a reflection-based dependency injection framework. Unfortunately, Guice doesn't perform well on Android. For example, in my latest project it took from 1 to 1.5 seconds to initialize an injector.

At some moment the RoboGuice developer decided to improve performance of his library by doing some work at compile time and that's what RoboBlender is about. It creates an annotation database at compile time and RoboGuice uses it this database at runtime for searching injection points. You can read more about RoboBlender [here](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/RoboBlender-wiki). This approach required a lot of changes in Guice so the RoboGuice author had to fork it and even sent a [pull request](https://github.com/google/guice/pull/880) to Guice. But this PR was rejected mainly because it contradicts the idea of the Guice library (to be a runtime DI framework).

Sorry for such a long intro and here's an answer to your question. When calling `RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases(false)` you ask RoboGuice to handle everything at runtime via reflection. In other words RoboGuice works just like original Guice and that's not very fast. When you're trying to use annotation databases and your application crashes it may happen because annotation databases cannot be found. Maybe you forgot to add         `<meta-data android:name="roboguice.annotations.packages" android:value="..."/>` to `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Finally, I wouldn't recommend you to use Guice or RoboGuice on Android, because the former is extremely slow and the latter is broken by design. It's much better to use a compile time DI library such as [Dagger](http://google.github.io/dagger/) and it shouldn't take a lot of time to switch to it.

Comment: Hi @Michael! Thank you so much for your great response! Now everything has sense! I deleted `RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases(false)` and the exception didn't appeared, maybe I was doing something wrong. About your response, you've earned the bounty

Answer (score 2):

Roboguice now moved to version 4.0.0. This is available on [github](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice), as branch `rg-4-final`. In gradle, you can use it as

```
compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:4.0.0'
provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:4.0.0'
```

I had issues with getting Roboblender to work before, but in 4.0.0 it works like a charm.

There are changes though. Look at the Astroboy example for how to use it. You don't extend Activities or Fragments any more, you inject members in each of them like so:

```
RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectMembers(this);
```

They abandoned `@InjectView` and `@InjectResource`, you now use Butterknife for injecting views, and resources you get in the normal Android way. Don't forget to initialize Roboguice in your application:

```
RoboGuice.setupBaseApplicationInjector(this, new MyModule(), new OtherModule());
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Not if they would just update the site documentation to 4.0 :)

Comment: I don't know why they haven't.

Comment: ` No implementation for android.content.Context was bound.
                                                                       while locating android.content.Context` Using roboguice 4.0

Comment: Injection of standard classes, like Context, has been removed from Roboguice. You need to create a provider to inject a context.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend you use butterknife. It's much more easier if you use android studio it also have plug in which allow you to generate auto view injection just once click:

useful documentation: https://github.com/avast/android-butterknife-zelezny

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but my whole app has been done using RogoGuice. I'll use it in my next app

Comment: ButterKnife has nothing to do with dependency injection.